# Html viewport not scaling to mobile phone

Tags: html, viewport

I have a web app built with iweb kit that looks great in Android and iPhones.
The only issue is, when on a mobile, you can grab the screen and move it to the left for a good distance and all you see is white. It does not do this if I move it to the right.
I have my meta tag set such as this `<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />`.

I also have the body and html css tags set to, `margin: 0, padding: 0; width: 100%, height: 100%`

I have tried to correct the movement of the app on the screen via javascript but it's a no go.
Has anyone ran into this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any divs that are position:fixed? I had an overflow problem like this with a menu on a site I designed. Android and iPhone don't seem to handle fixed positioning the way desktop browsers do.

You also might not want to use "user-scalable=no" if you can avoid it because it can seriously cut down on usability between screen sizes or font sizes for people with disabilities.

Comment: I searched my css files and found no fixed position elements. I wish I could use Firebug but it fits the screen perfectly on my computer browser.

Comment: I have scoured my code but I cannot find where this extra space to the right is coming from.

Comment: Can you link to your HTML/CSS so we can look at it?

Comment: It's for work so I can't, but what did work out was setting the viewport width to 450. I tested it on the iPhone and android and it seems to work.

Comment: Did you test it on androids of different screen size/resolution? And in landscape mode? If you fix the viewport at 450 it might not scale correctly if the screen is larger.

Comment: Hmm, strange, i have some fixed divs on the page and it scale perfectly on the iPad3 but not on Samsung Galaxy S. Anyone knows what to do?